# list::empty() multi-threaded behavior?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, race-condition, stdlist

I have a list that I want different threads to grab elements from.  In order to avoid locking the mutex guarding the list when it's empty, I check `empty()` before locking.

It's okay if the call to `list::empty()` isn't right 100% of  the time.  I only want to avoid crashing or disrupting concurrent `list::push()` and `list::pop()` calls.

Am I safe to assume VC++ and Gnu GCC will only sometimes get `empty()` wrong and nothing worse?

```
if(list.empty() == false){ // unprotected by mutex, okay if incorrect sometimes
    mutex.lock();
    if(list.empty() == false){ // check again while locked to be certain
         element = list.back();
         list.pop_back();
    }
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: No, you can't assume this. You could use a concurrent container like VC's [concurrent_queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrent-queue-class?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Fureeish This should be an answer. I would add that `std::list::size` has guaranteed constant time complexity, which basically means that the size (number of nodes) needs to be stored in a separate variable; let's call it `size_`. `std::list::empty` then likely returns something as `size_ == 0`, and the concurrent read and write of `size_` would cause data race, therefore, UB.

Comment: @DanielLangr How is "constant time" measured? Is it on a single function call or the complete program?

Comment: @curiousguy It's not constant time. It's constant [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). I would simply say that the runtime should be independent of the number of list nodes.

Comment: @DanielLangr That doesn't answer my q. How is that evaluated? On a single call or the whole program?

Comment: @curiousguy Your Q is not related to my original comment. I don't understand why you have addressed it to me. You can measure time for whatever you are interested about.

Comment: @curiousguy It is not amortized constant time complexity but simply constant time complexity, i.e. "on a single a call" (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have not found an explanation of what non amortized means in the std, and no one was been able to define it. How could amortized vs. non amortized even be observable?

Comment: @curiousguy: DanielLangr did answer your question by "independent of the number of list nodes", that is exact definition of O(1) wich means that every call is executed in less than some constant time, regardless of number of elements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions The other option (until C++11) would be linear = O(n) meaning, that size would have to count the elements (linked list), wich would be even worse for the concurrency (more obvious data-race than non-atomic read/write on counter).

Comment: @curiousguy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis. Notice how [Table 90](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/containers#tab:containers.associative.requirements) in the C++17 draft has "amortized constant" for e.g. single element `erase` for associative containers, but `empty()` always has "constant" ([Table 83](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/containers#tab:containers.container.requirements)).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thank you. The WP page doesn't explain the diff between amortized complexity spec and non amortized. There are other issues. You refer to literature that goes to infinity but C/C++ have finite datatypes. Nobody in the std committees has ever tried to work that out AFAIK.

Comment: @curiousguy Well did you look for any other resource? Or do you expect me to link and explain all of complexity theory? Here's another link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Complexity_measures. Your "finite vs infinite" paradox is also irrelevant. There is no issue with analyzing the (theoretical) time complexity of an algorithm for inputs tending to infinity, no matter whether the input size is limited for practical C++ programs. It's a non-issue. I recommend you research the fundamentals of complexity theory if these are the points you bring up.

Comment: @MaxLanghof So **a fundamental logical contradiction is "_a non-issue_"?** How can you analyse asymptotic behavior of `X<2**N`, N = 32 or 64? *Are we officially done logical consistency here in the **language lawyer** world?* Physicists talk about "small volume of fluid", "small length of a cable", which sounds really ill define but which can be formalized as *dV*, *dL* with limits and integration and stuff. Some students are even exposed to badly specified d-something notation. But there is a sound formalization. There is none AFAIK in C++.

Comment: @curiousguy: Taking your own example with dV, time complexity is the same math - limits. All these things are either defined recursively, or in a form of "There exists C such that f(N) < C for every N" - that is the definition of O(1) (for given/every HW there exists constant C such that the algo ends in less-than C-time on any input). Amortized means *on average*, which means that some inputs may take longer to process (e.g. re-hash / re-alloc needed), but it is still constant on average (assuming all possible inputs).

Comment: @firda Yes there is a vague notion of average. People in the C++ committee have told me that. They were enable to be more specific. Average of what? Many operations? Which operations, how? This is a mess.

Comment: @curiousguy The C++ standard says: Does the _algorithm_ you implemented for `empty()` have constant (asymptotic) time complexity? Does the one for `push_back` have amortized (asymptotic) time complexity? Then your implementation is standard-compliant. Otherwise it's not. That's it. Whether any lower order constants or factors in the complexity dominate the real cost for any realistic input is not the concern of the standard.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Scalar types are finite, so there is no such thing. Also, you have not provided a definition for "amortized" and no committee member was able to help me either.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Last time? What story was that? My understanding is fine. You are making up stuff;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It's okay if the call to `list::empty()` isn't right 100% of the time.

No, it is not okay.  If you check if the list is empty outside of some synchronization mechanism (locking the mutex) then you have a data race.  Having a data race means you have undefined behavior.  Having undefined behavior means we can no longer reason about the program and any output you get is "correct".

If you value your sanity, you'll take the performance hit and lock the mutex before checking.  That said, the list might not even be the correct container for you.  If you can let us know exactly what you are doing with it, we might be able to suggest a better container.

Comment: Personal perspective, call `list::empty()` is a read action that has nothing to do with `race-condition`

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn If they are adding elements into the list then it most definitely causes a data race as you are writing and reading the size at the same time.

Comment: `race-condition` only happens if you use 2 threads to write a data at the same time, it's is `write-write`. Not `read-write`

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn That is false.  A race condition is `read-write` or `write-write`.  If you don't beleive me, give [the standard section on data races](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races) a read

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn: Imagine the size changing from 0x00FF to 0x0100 on 8-bit MCU, where the write **is not atomic** - you get 0x0000 for a split second during the multi-byte write.

Comment: @firda I've read the definition of `race-condition`, it states that where there is **at least** 1 write. But I am not sure why it causes conflicts when there is only 1 write. Does it relate to the sequential circuit?

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn: Because neither the write nor the read are guaranteed to be atomic, therefore can be executed simultaneously, therefore the read can get something totally wrong (called torn read). Imagine write changing 0x00FF to 0x0100 in little endian 8-bit MCU, starting by rewriting low 0xFF to 0x00 and the read now gets exactly that zero, reading both bytes (writing thread slowed or suspended), write continues by updating high byte to 0x01, but the reading thread already got wrong value (neither 0x00FF, nor 0x0100 but unexpected 0x0000).

Comment: Oh, I assume that reading a 64 bit value is atomic by default.

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn It may on some architectures but the C++ virtual machine offers no such guarantee.  Even if your hardware did, it would be legal for the compiler to optimize the code in a way that you would never see a change since unless there is thread synchronization it can assume it is running only a single thread and optimize accordingly.

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn What makes you believe that a write-write conflict is more serious than a read-write conflict?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica "_A race condition is read-write or write-write_" Whenever any threads non trivially share any data, whether using mutexes or atomics, you will have race conditions. Races is a normal element of MT programming. You have to make sure no race leads to an erroneous result, but they are not bugs.

Comment: @curiousguy that is not true.  You can have unlimited threads share the same data as long as you only read from it.  It's when a writer gets into the mix when you must have synchronization

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica "_that is not true_" Not sure which comment you're replying to. I quote some words of the comment when I reply to avoid such ambiguities. "_You can have (...) only read from it._" Of course. Not sure where I implied otherwise. (?)

Comment: @firda "_8-bit MCU, where the write is not atomic_" Do you know of any C++ impl on such arch?

Comment: @curiousguy: I believe you can find some 8bit AVR/Arduino. I personally work with ATtiny and ATmega, but use pure C, not C++ on them (but I think AtmelStudio can support C++ on these, it is just that I opt for pure C on those tiny MCUs). The point here is that `int` is not guaranteed to be atomic on every platform, `std::atomic_int` is, but `std::atomic<int>::is_lock_free` may be false on those 8bit MCUs (or on very old x86/Z80 - I used to have Didactic M / ZX Spectrum).

Comment: @firda The original x86 supported MT?

Answer (score 6):

There is a read and a write (most probably to the `size` member of `std::list`, if we assume that it's named like that) that are not synchronized **in reagard to each other**. Imagine that one thread calls `empty()` (in your outer `if()`) while the other thread entered the inner `if()` and executes `pop_back()`. You are then reading a variable that is, possibly, being modified. This is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As an example of how things could go wrong:

A sufficiently smart compiler could see that `mutex.lock()` cannot possibly change the `list.empty()` return value and thus skip the inner `if` check completely, eventually leading to a `pop_back` on a list that had its last element removed after the first `if`.

Why can it do that? There is no synchronization in `list.empty()`, thus if it were changed concurrently that would constitute a data race. The standard says that programs shall not have data races, so the compiler will take that for granted (otherwise it could perform almost no optimizations whatsoever). Hence it can assume a single-threaded perspective on the unsynchronized `list.empty()` and conclude that it must remain constant.

This is only one of several optimizations (or hardware behaviors) that could break your code.

Comment: Current compilers don't even seem to want to optimize `a.load()+a.load()` ...

Comment: @curiousguy How would like that optimized? You request full sequential consistency there, so you'll get that...

Comment: @MaxLanghof You don't think the optimization to `a.load()*2` is obvious? Not even `a.load(rel)+b.load(rel)-a.load(rel)` is optimized anyway. Nothing is. Why do you expect locks (which by essence mostly have seq consistency) to be more optimized?

Comment: @curiousguy Because the memory ordering of non-atomic accesses (here before and after the lock) and atomics are entirely different? I don't expect the lock to be optimized "more", I expect that unsynchronized accesses be optimized more than sequentially consistent accesses. The presence of the lock is irrelevant for my point. And no, the compiler is not allowed to optimize `a.load() + a.load()` to `2 * a.load()`. Feel free to ask a question about this if you want to know more.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have no idea what you are even trying to say. Locks are essentially sequentially consistent. Why would implementation try to do optimizations on some threading primitives (locks) and not some others (atomics)? Do you expect non-atomics accesses to be optimized around uses of atomics?

Comment: @curiousguy _"Do you expect non-atomics accesses to be optimized around uses of atomics?"_ Of course I do! Here is `clang` doing that, skipping one of the loads of `a` (although `gcc` isn't there yet): https://godbolt.org/z/jz-6fh. In the case of locks (which tend to involve syscalls, i.e. black boxes) I don't expect any particular compiler to work it out at this point (hence "sufficiently smart"). But you shouldn't base code correctness only on what compilers can optimize _right now_.

Comment: @curiousguy Also, where would you see the difference between `auto x = a.load() + a.load();` and `while (a.load() != 0);`? The latter is clearly a spin lock and would be straight up broken if the compiler assumed that subsequent atomic loads had to yield identical values, so why should it be allowed to optimize the former to `auto x = 2 * a.load();`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof "_skipping one of the loads of `a`_" What is `f.load(std::memory_order_release);` supposed to do?

Comment: @curiousguy Yeah the second load ordering is somewhat meaningless. If you use `std::memory_order_relaxed` instead then both compilers optimize to only two loads of the non-atomic. Doesn't really change the point. I also don't understand the second comment (it spins until `a != 0`, what's "twice" about it?), please elaborate.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Just the contrary: I just meant that `a.load()+a.load()` doesn't spin indefinitely; not that a spin lock does something twice. So a compiler that would optimize some code w/o loop would not necessarily optimize code w/ loop. Sorry for the confusion. (I will play with godbolt to see what loads are optimized.)